# Javascript finding the Maximum

Tags: javascript

So i have a script with 3 scores, and I want the code to find the highest score and print a message based on which variable is the highest score. I know that `Math.max()` finds the maximum, but I want it to find the variable name that has the maximum.  How do i do this?

Comment: Unless you store the values in an object, there's no way to get a variable's name from its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
var score1 = 42;
var score2 = 13;
var score3 = 22;
var max = Math.max(score1, score2, score3);
if (max === score1) {
  // Then score1 has the max
} else if (max === score2) {
  // Then score2 has the max
} else {
  // Then score3 has the max 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with Math.max if you just want to compare the three.

You just want to check if one value is higher than both other values:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 22;
var c = 37;

if (a > b && a > c) {
  // print hooray for a!
} else if (b > a && b > c) {
  // print hooray for b!
} else if (c > b && c > a) {
  // print hooray for c!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array, sort the array and then take the first position.

```
   var score1 = 42;
    var score2 = 13;
    var score3 = 22;

    var a=[score1,score2,score3];

    function sortNumber(a,b){return b - a;}

    var arrayMax=a.sort(sortNumber)[0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GKaGt/6/

Comment: He wants the name of the variable, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your values in an object, loop through, and find the biggest.

```
var scores = {score1: 42, score2: 13, score3: 22},
maxKey = '', maxVal = 0;
for(var key in scores){
   if(scores.hasOwnProperty(key) && scores[key] > maxVal){
      maxKey = key;
      maxVal = scores[key];
   }
}
alert(maxKey); // 'score1'
```